# RViz POINTS color bug or doing something wrong

Tags: ros, rviz, ros-melodic, points

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I am using RViz to visualize some processed point cloud data. I am using visualization_msgs::Marker::POINTS.

According to tutorials I should be able to do something like this.

```
visualization_msgs::Marker points;
points.type = visualization_msgs::Marker::POINTS;
points.color.a = 1.0;
points.color.r = 1.0;
```

or using colors:

```
std_msgs::ColorRGBA col;
col.a = 1.;
col.r = 1.;
points.colors.push_back(col);
```

However, none of these two approaches seems to be working. All I get are white points. No change regarding the color.

I just wanted to ask you if I am doing something wrong or it is indeed a bug. (Ubuntu 18.04 - Melodic)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/337916/rviz-points-color-bug-or-doing-something-wrong/) by [ligazetom](https://answers.ros.org/users/49515/ligazetom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2019-11-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-11-19**:
This appears to be a cross-post of [ros-visualization/rviz#1444](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues/1444).

**Comment by [ligazetom](https://answers.ros.org/users/49515/ligazetom/) on 2019-11-19**:
Well yes. Is my issue I created today, because I found out even tutorials are not working. The moment they approve it is bug I will post response here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It was caused by using Nouveau driver instead of proprietary nVidia driver. After switching, everything seems to be working.

---

Originally posted by [ligazetom](https://answers.ros.org/users/49515/ligazetom/) with karma: 28 on 2019-11-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1